# Pass a jsonstring to the service and convert it to stream on the server side

Tags: json, wcf, stream

i have this

{"invoices":{"POSWorkstationID":"POS7","POSClerkID":"admin","CustomerName":"Alice in Wonderland Tours","IsFreightOverwrite":true},"invoiceDetails":[{"ItemDescription":"Old World Lamppost","QuantityOrdered":"1","SalePriceRate":" $107.99","ExtPriceRate":"107.99","ItemType":"Stock","LineNum":1,"WarehouseCode":"Main"}]}

Now i want to pass this on my server using rest and convert it to stream. My service code is here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594382/convert-json-to-stream-in-wcf

Comment: Any specific reason on why you want to send it as stream? Also can you post the DataContract for Invoices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find some sample code to get your scenario working:

On my Server:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        public string CreateInvoice(Stream xmlStream)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.ContentLength];
            int read = -1;
            while (read != 0)
            {
                read = xmlStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }           
            System.Text.Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII;
            string jsonobjectstring = enc.GetString(buffer);
            JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            object jsonobject = json.DeserializeObject(jsonobjectstring);
            return "Recieved the json text on server";
           //MaintainInvoice(xmlStream, InvoiceMaintainance.CreateInvoice);
        }
```

I have modified the server method logic so that i can test it. Once you get the stream on the server you can use your logic to return the invoice object as needed.

Now on client side to invoke the rest service i use the below code:

```
private string UseHttpWebApproachByteArray(string serviceUrl, string resourceUrl, string method, byte[] requestBody)
        {
            string responseMessage = null;            
            var request = WebRequest.Create(string.Concat(serviceUrl, resourceUrl)) as HttpWebRequest;
            if (request != null)
            {                
                request.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                request.Method = method;
            }            
            if (method == "POST" && requestBody != null)
            {                
                request.ContentLength = requestBody.Length;
                using (Stream postStream = request.GetRequestStream())                    
                    postStream.Write(requestBody, 0, requestBody.Length);
            }

            if (request != null)
            {
                var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                    if (responseStream != null)
                    {
                        var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

                        responseMessage = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    responseMessage = response.StatusDescription;
                }
            }
            return responseMessage;
        }

private void Test()
{
      string jsonText = "{\"invoices\":{\"POSWorkstationID\":\"POS7\",\"POSClerkID\":\"admin\",\"CustomerName\":\"Alice in Wonderland Tours\",\"IsFreightOverwrite\":true},\"invoiceDetails\":[{\"ItemDescription\":\"Old World Lamppost\",\"QuantityOrdered\":\"1\",\"SalePriceRate\":\" $107.99\",\"ExtPriceRate\":\"107.99\",\"ItemType\":\"Stock\",\"LineNum\":1,\"WarehouseCode\":\"Main\"}]}";
      System.Text.Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII;
      byte[] jsonBytes = enc.GetBytes(jsonText);
      UseHttpWebApproachByteArray(serviceBaseUrl, resourceUrl, method, jsonBytes);
}
```

Comment: hi, i just would like to add if i will access it using jquery and ajax how will i do it on the client side? thank you